# Initialzing a 2d vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, stl, 2d-vector

I know that you can initialize a 1d vector with some value in the following way:

```
vector<int> vec(10, 100); //creates a vector of size 10 and each element = 100
```

Now I would like to do the same thing with a 2d vector. I know the following would give an error, because the size of columns is not specified:

```
vector<vector<int> > vec(10, 100);
```

So, is there any way to accomplish this? Also, I want to keep the column size same for each vector in the 2d vector (i.e., an nxn grid).

Or maybe I can use the "std::fill()" function in some way to accomplish this? And can this functionality be extended to an nxm grid?

Comment: A "2D vector" is a vector of vectors. So if you know how to initialize a vector, you know how to initialize a vector of vectors.

Comment: You can use `boost::multi_array`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
vector<vector<int>> vec(10, vector<int>(10, 100));
                //       n              m   value
```

This will create a vector of 10 vectors of size 10 and with elements initialized to 100.